# Unexpected evaluation result of image source in ReactTestUtils

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I got some unexpected test result of ReactTestUtils. Here is the code:

The source:

```
var React = require('react');

module.exports = React.createClass({
  render() {
    var data = this.props.data;

    return (
      <div>
        <img className="photo" src={data['photograph-url']} alt={data['photograph-caption']}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

The test by using Jest

```
    var React = require('react/addons');
    var TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils;
    var data = {
      "photograph-url": "photograph url",
      "photograph-caption": "photograph caption"
    };

    var details = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
      <Details data={data}/>
    );
    var photo = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithClass(details, "photo").getDOMNode();

expect(agentPhoto.src).toEqual('photograph url');
```

Surprisingly, the test is failed, because the result of agentPhoto.src returning "/Users/...../photograph url", which is some kind of my folder path.

However, then I change the "photograph url" with real http source image "http://...". It is working fine.

I dont know what is reason behind that

Many thanks in advance

Comment: How are you running your Jest tests? Locally served html? Command line? Grunt/Gulp?

Comment: command line and I am using grunt. The way I run the test is just "jest"

Answer (score 0):

My best guess that jsdom is trying to figure out how to resolve the relative url `photograph url` and because its being run from a directory in your `/User/` dir its resolving it to that.

You can either use a fake http address for your testing data or validate the props rather than the dom elements like this:

```
var React = require('react/addons');
var TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils;
var data = {
  "photograph-url": "photograph url",
  "photograph-caption": "photograph caption"
};

var details = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
  <Details data={data}/>
);
var photo = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithClass(details, "photo");

expect(photo.props.src).toEqual("photograph url");
```

Comment: I think the difference is "props.src" instead of "src" directly. However, the the result is "Cannot read property 'src' of undefined" .